Methods to evaluate unsupervised algorithms over multiple applications?
I am using a clustering algorithm $A_{\mathbf{\theta}}$ with hyperparameters $\mathbf{\theta}$ on datasets ${X_i}$.  I.e., for each of $X_0, X_1, X_2 \ldots$ I apply $A_\mathbf{\theta}$, and obtain a clustering on that dataset.  I am aware of many metrics to evaluate the quality of clusterings on a single dataset.  Are there metrics that are especially suited to evaluate models over multiple datasets?  One naive method might be to pick an arbitrary metric for a single dataset, and then aggregate (sum/mean/min) over all datasets.  Are there any other metrics that might be able to take into account the re-use of my hyperparameters and model selection over multiple datasets?
